# Xamarin Binding Data from ItemSource to a Labels Text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, binding

i´ve got 2 things: second one is a list. when i´m clicking the "+1" button, a new element is createt with the name "list.Count"(so first one is 1, 2, 3, 4...). this is working very good. but for the first thing i wanna have only the vurrent value of the "Text"(from the current newest object in the list). But: i do not only want a counter. Maybe you can unterstand better if you check out my code:

```
<StackLayout>
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Label Text="Erg:" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Path=Nummer, Source=Num}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" /> *
    </StackLayout>
        <Button Text="+1" Command="{Binding CountUpCommand}" />  **
    <Button Text="Erg x Erg" />
</StackLayout>
<Label Text="--------------" />
<StackLayout>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Nummer}"> **
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell 
                Text="{Binding Num}" **
                />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

so my question is at the Line with only one * at the end. the other 3 lines with two ** are working. what do i have to do to get the right Binding-Path or -Statment or something like this, to get the number shown up at labelsText ? i think there´s something missing like "itemsource"..

so here s the code from Itemsource (from My CounterVM):

```
    public ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel> Nummer { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel>();


    public ICommand CountUpCommand { get; private set; }

    public CounterViewModel()
    {

        CountUpCommand = new Command(CountUp);
    }


    public void CountUp()
    {
        int newNumber = Nummer.Count + 1;
        Nummer.Add(new NumberViewModel { Num = newNumber});
    }
```

and here the NumverVM, same code as in number.cs:

```
public class NumberViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your thread to explain this in more detail please? So when you press the Button "+1", a new item is added to the ListViews ItemsSource?

Comment: yeah wait a second, i´ll add the code behind aswell

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. you said: "but for the first thing i wanna have only the vurrent value of the "Text"(from the current newest object in the list). But: i do not only want a counter.". explain that a little better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Property inside your ViewModel to get the correct value:

```
public class CounterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public string LastItemsText => Nummer.Last()?.Num.ToString();

    public ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel> Nummer { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel>();

    public ICommand CountUpCommand { get; private set; }

    public CounterViewModel()
    {
        CountUpCommand = new Command(CountUp);
    }

    public void CountUp()
    {
        int newNumber = Nummer.Count + 1;
        Nummer.Add(new NumberViewModel { Num = newNumber});
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LastItemsText));
    }
}
```

And instead of

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=Nummer, Source=Num}"
```

do this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding LastItemsText}"
```

Comment: no, in your solution are different faults... the first problem for me is the data binding, why is in the xaml the second Text="{Binding Num}" working and the first not?

Comment: You mean this <TextCell Text="{Binding Num}" /> ?

Comment: my first goal is only to "see" something at the first Label (the one with a * at the end of the line). its empty right now.

Comment: `<Label Text="{Binding Path=Nummer, Source=Num}"` cannot work, because `Nummer` is a collection, not a single model. So you have to get the one Model where you want to access the Property `Sum`. Have you tried my code? This only works, AFTER you clicked the +1-Button

Comment: i tried, but there where several errors (because of "int to string" at the last() method, and it didnt get the propertychanged staff even with getting the namespace...)

Comment: and as you can see in my code: there s a textcell where it s working.. so the only different is that the secont textcell has the "itemsource bniding" from the listview

Comment: I see, thought you know how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Then let me add some additional lines for you

Comment: For sure the TextCell is working because you don't reference the ObservalbleCollection, you reference the Model inside the collection.

Comment: i allready have Inotify stuff implemented.. dont know why it doesnt recognize the propchange

Comment: and there´s no posibility to do this with the label aswell?

Comment: I don't know of one that easy as I told you

Comment: So for your conversion from int to string, just add .ToString() at the end. I edited the solution for you